# IP security policy on windows 2003

Tags: windows, security, registry, policy

Does anyone know how I can:

1. create IP security policy
2. manage IP filters and IP filter actions

PROGRAMMATICALLY on windows 2003? Not use Microsoft GUI utility.

I tried to achieve this by programming with windows registry, 
all data I need that is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\windows\IPSec\Policy\Local
but I have no idea with some data. e.g the value of IPsecData,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not programmatically but not GUI either:
You can use command-line netsh ipsec...
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739550(WS.10).aspx